# How to complete Warcraft II BNE: Custom Scenario (Classic) - Expansion [Orc; Death Knight] (Gauntlet) scenario?

Tags: warcraft-2

So, I am playing Warcraft II custom scenario in Battle dot net Edition. I was able to play as human campaign with Mage but I was not able finish it with Footman scenario because it can't attack flyers.
I was trying to play as Orc campaign and I thought I will use Death Knight because it's a mage with ranged attack. To my horror it has only 18 hitpoints. Is it possible to complete this mission successfully without using cheat?
Below is the screenshot and my own recorded video for more information. Thanks for the help.

[image: Warcraft II BNE: Custom Scenario (Classic) - Expansion [Orc; Death Knight] (Gauntlet)]

[Warcraft II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN24pHEt5eQ)

Comment: Not much I can do to help, I'm afraid, but oh man, the memories! (By the way, it might be good to point out the link goes to your own video, showcasing the scenario. You can also feature it more prominently, or it might receive spam flags.)

Comment: Edited it. Thanks.